# Azure CLI Bash - attaching an app insights resource to api managment

Tags: bash, azure-cli

I can create an api management instance

```
    az apim create \
        --name "$apimName" \
        --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" \
        --publisher-name 'Publisher' \
        --publisher-email 'Myemail@email.com.au' \
        --tags "${resourceTags[@]}"
```

and I can create an app insights instance

```
    az monitor app-insights component create \
        --app "${apimName}-appins" \
        --location "australiaeast" \
        --resource-group "$resourceGroupName" \
        --tags "${resourceTags[@]}"
```

How do I attach the api insights to api management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command below, replace the values with yours.

```
az resource create --resource-type 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/loggers' -g '<apim-group-name>' -n '<apim-name>/loggers/<appinsight-name>' --properties '{
    "loggerType":"applicationInsights",
    "description": null,
    "credentials": {
      "instrumentationKey": "<Instrumentation-Key-of-your-appinsight>"
    },
    "isBuffered": true,
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<appinsight-group-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appinsight-name>"
}'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I add a variable here?  "instrumentationKey": "$instrumentationKey".  Its giving me Invalid instrumentation key for Application Insights Logger even though the variable has the correct key

Comment: @David It is an escape issue, because the json is in the `' '`, so it will not be recognized as the var, I am not an expert in bash, I recommend you to ask it in a new question.

Comment: for anyone else wondering how to overcome the single quote issue as mentioned by Joy, use double quotes everywhere and escape all of them with a backslash, except for the outer quotes containing the json - like this `\"`